# Bootstrap - button style not being applied to buttons

Tags: html, css, events, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get these buttons to conform to my css, but they are not being style.

I made new buttons and they also were not styled to my css. However I noticed that the text was being uppercased, which I have as part of the css, which leads me to think part of it is wrong.

```
 <section id="gallery" class="content-section text-center">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Show all</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="filterSelection('sealion')">Sea Lions</button>
      </div>

.btn {
  font-family: 'Cabin', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-default {
  color: #42DCA3;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-default:focus, .btn-default:hover {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #42DCA3;
}
```

The expected result is that the buttons are black rectangles with white text and a green border. Once a button is hovered, the button solidifies in the green color.

Answer (score 0):

Add Class `btn-default` to `button` `tag`

```
<section id="gallery" class="content-section text-center">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <button class="btn btn-default active" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Show all</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="filterSelection('sealion')">Sea Lions</button>

      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/puezgn9v/4/

Comment: That only seems to work for the first selection, the one showing all images, the one for sea lions still shows a regular button with no css.

Comment: Thanks, I see what I needed to do now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class `btn-default` in `button` first and give `css` using all classes of button together like `.btn.active.btn-default` to override `bootstrap` `css`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.btn {
  font-family: 'Cabin', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn.active.btn-default {
  color: #42DCA3;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn.active.btn-default:focus, .btn.active.btn-default:hover {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #42DCA3;
}
</style>

<section id="gallery" class="content-section text-center">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <button class="btn active btn-default" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Show all</button>
          <button type="button" onclick="filterSelection('sealion')">Sea Lions</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.btn {
  font-family: 'Cabin', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn.active.btn-default {
  color: #42DCA3;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn.active.btn-default:focus, .btn.active.btn-default:hover {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #42DCA3;
}
.btn.active.btn-primary {
  color: #42DCA3;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn.active.btn-primary:focus, .btn.active.btn-primary:hover {
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #42DCA3;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #42DCA3;
}
</style>

<section id="gallery" class="content-section text-center">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <button class="btn active btn-default" onclick="filterSelection('all')">Show all</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary active" onclick="filterSelection('sealion')">Sea Lions</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

try this code,it is working now